# removing dot using regular expression removes * too

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove certain special characters from a string.
For the same am using

```
    replace(/[()-/.]/gi, '');
```

This is working fine , however I realized that it also removes '*'.Any idea why??
If I remove '.' from the expression it's working fine ,so I guess that is creating some issue which am not sure of

Answer (score 2):

Problem is unescaped hyphen appearing in the middle. Make it like this:

```
replace(/[()\/.-]/gi, '');
```

When an unescaped hyphen appears in the middle of the character class it acts as a range

- `)` is ascii 41
- `/` is ascii 47
- `*` is ascii 42 hence your regex negates `*` since `-` acts on all characters in the range `41-47`

Answer (score 2):

The hyphen needs to be escaped because of its position inside of the character class. You can as well remove the `i` (case-insensitive) flag, it is not necessary because you don't include proper characters.

```
/[()\-\/.]/g
```

**Note:** Inside of a character class the hyphen has **special meaning**. You can place it as the first or last character of the class. In some regex implementations, you can also place directly after a range. If you place the hyphen anywhere else you need to precede it with a backslash in order to add it to your character class.

Comment: Thanks guess will have to dig in the concepts a little bit more